# How can I make a class both implement an Interface and inherit from another class

Tags: c#, interface, derived-class, interface-implementation

I want my class to implement an interface and also get the additional properties from Auditable table. Can I do both? I have tried to do it here but I am getting an error in my IDE.

```
public partial class ObjectiveDetail : IEquatable<ObjectiveDetail>, AuditableTable
{
    ...
}

public abstract class AuditableTable : IAuditableTable
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: `I am getting an error in my IDE` . What error?

Comment: "An" error, huh?  If only we knew which...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must change

```
public partial class ObjectiveDetail : IEquatable<ObjectiveDetail>,  AuditableTable
```

to

```
public partial class ObjectiveDetail :   AuditableTable, IEquatable<ObjectiveDetail>
```

In C#, you can inherit **one class** and implement **multiple interfaces** and you **must put class first**.

Answer (score 3):

public SubClass : BaseClass, IInterface

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do both, but you have to put the base class first:

```
public partial class ObjectiveDetail : AuditableTable, IEquatable<ObjectiveDetail>
```

Answer (score 2):

Base class first and then Interface, should work

Answer (score 0):

Nothing prevents you from both implementing an interface and inheriting from a class in the same class, C# only doesn't support multiple inheritance (inheriting from multiple diferent classes) so you don't need to do anything, it should just work.

Comment: Without stating the error, the question is pretty useless however